# Steam API ISteamUserStats - How to Get Achievment Image

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I am currently trying to move my application from Steam Xml Api to Steam Web Api.

In the old Xml Api I had for each achievement following xml:

```
<achievement closed="0">
    <iconClosed>http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/205830/d21efac1184e37b4b344d18639db18cf40979018.jpg</iconClosed>
    <iconOpen>http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/205830/7a4517495fba9f34642efd3983a561f55770f36c.jpg</iconOpen>
    <name>Manic Matcher</name>
    <apiname>st_ach_24</apiname>
    <description>Achieve 5 Consecutive Quick Matches</description>
</achievement>
```

This is Containing Achievement Pics.

In the ISteamUserStats interface I get only this response:

```
{
"apiname": "ST_ACH_05",
"achieved": 0,
"name": "Silver Medal",
"description": "50 shot streak"
}
```

So, is there an Interface which give me the Image from ST_ACH_05? If not what can i do? Is it ok do use the deprecated XML Api?

References:

- https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/community_data
- https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

Comment: When Voting down, please explain why? I am new here. Is it the wrong Network site for this question? Which is the right? Is this Question Amateur which mean you have a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the [GetSchemaForGame](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetSchemaForGame) API call.

`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetSchemaForGame/v0002/?key=YOURKEY&appid=APPID&l=english&format=json`

`YOURKEY` is the API key you have gotten from Valve. `APPID` is the application ID of the game you are looking for.

The API has the following format (taken from the above Wiki link)

```
game

    gameName (string)
        Steam internal (non-localized) name of game. 
    gameVersion (int)
        Steam release version number currently live on Steam. 
    availableGameStats

        achievements (Optional) (array)

            name (string)
                API Name of achievement. 
            defaultvalue (int)
                Always 0 (player's default state is unachieved). 
            displayName (string)
                Display title string of achievement. 
            hidden (int)
                If achievement is hidden to the user before earning achievement, value is 1. 0 if public. 
            description (string)
                Display description string of achievement. 
            icon (string)
                Absolute URL of earned achievement icon art. 
            icongray (string)
                Absolute URL of un-earned achievement icon art. 

        stats (Optional) (array)

            name (string)
                API name of stat. 
            defaultvalue (int)
                Default value of stat. 
            displayName (string)
                Developer provided name of string.
```

With a data result (from TF2, appid 440) looking like this:

```
"achievements": [
                {
                    "name": "TF_PLAY_GAME_EVERYCLASS",
                    "defaultvalue": 0,
                    "displayName": "Head of the Class",
                    "hidden": 0,
                    "description": "Play a complete round with every class.",
                    "icon": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/tf_play_game_everyclass.jpg",
                    "icongray": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/tf_play_game_everyclass_bw.jpg"
                },
```